# Add commit with previous commits prefixes

Tags: git, git-bash

I would like to create a bash script (or sth. similar if needed) which on the new branch will create a commit message with previous commits prefixes, but only the ones after the last master commit.

Example:

```
master <prefix1>:<msg1>
                       \
                        develop <prefix2>:<msg2> - <prefix3>:<msg3>
                                                                   \ 
                                                                    newbranch <prefix2 prefix3>
```

Any ideas how to start this script? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the messages of commits since `master`, you can use :

```
# from master to your current active commit :
git log --pretty="%s" master..HEAD

# from master to develop :
git log --pretty="%s" master..develop
```

(check the "Pretty Formats" section of [`git help log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) : `"%s"` stands for "the first line of the commit message")

With the diagram in your question, this should output :

```
$ git log --pretty="%s" master..develop
<prefix3>:<msg3>
<prefix2>:<msg2>
```

You can now use other text processing commands to extract your prefixes and build a string.

For example, using `awk` :

```
# will extract the prefixes :
git log ... | awk '{ print $1 }'

# will build a single string with extracted prefixes, from oldest to newest :
git log ... | awk '{ prefix=$1" "prefix; } END { print prefix }'
```

Comment: I don't understand awk part, so if <prefix> in real life is always ```ABCD-<5 digits>```, example ```ABCD-12345: This is an example commit```, how would it look in the code?

Comment: Strange, when I run it it prints whole commit (prefix + message), but when I've dropped ```-F``` it works fine

Comment: Any idea how to drop duplicated prefixes?

Comment: if you don't care about the chronological order of prefixes : '... | sort -u | awk ...'. If you care : write a script in a language you know ; or still using awk : `awk '{ if (!seen[$1]++) prefix = $1" "prefix; } END { print prefix }`

Comment: Could you remove the ```-F``` from the main answer? then I could accept it ?

Comment: `-F` indicates what should ne used as a field separator. Depending on your shell (are you running your command from cmd.exe in Windows ?), you may have to put the `:` between quotes : `awk -F":"`

Comment: I'm running the code on ```bash, version 4.2.46```, and still with your newest solution the same happens

Comment: and what version of awk ? I'm running bash 5.1.4 on linux, my `awk --version` mentions "GNU Awk 5.1.0" (note : if not using the `-F` works for you, go with it :) I'm just hunting for details on what could be different between our two machines)

Comment: Awk: GNU Awk 4.0.2